# Hover effect if button is not disabled?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS rule:

```
button.medium.fade-btn:hover:not([disabled]) {
  color:red;
}
```

And HTML code:

```
<button class="medium fade-btn" disabled></button>
```

I need that hover effect works only when button is not disabled.

Comment: This all thing is ok,what is question?

Comment: That's [what you have?](https://jsfiddle.net/a1sd73s1/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't structured your selector properly

```
button.medium.fade-btn:hover:not([disabled])
```

In theory selects nothing, but is searching the children of button (which there are none) due to you putting it after the hover.

```
button.medium.fade-btn:not([disabled]):hover
```

Is the correct way.

Hover is the event so you want that happening on the not disabled button so it comes after everything else. Select the element and then use the hover as the last part. It may be easier to work with disabled: true/false as well.

Edit: This is either a browser compatibility problem, or your browser isn't liking just using disabled in the type selector. You should try using disabled=true in your selector and checking your browser version against the versions that :not() is supported in.

Comment: It does not work in both cases. Chrome browser. Now post jsfiddle

Comment: This could be due to browser compatibility, the second way is the valid way to write it regardless of the first working or not. People are saying it works for them and it worked for me in the fiddle so what browser are you using?

Comment: @OPV use disabled=true